# :after pseudo element creating twin circle

Tags: html, css

here i am doing a simple experiment with css .but this made me curious about the behaviour of css pseudo elements like :after & :before.Here inside a container circle there will be a rotatin half circle which is ok till now.But i wanted to create another circle using :after pseudo element.But it is creating two black circle ,but there supposed to be only one circle.From where the other sibling come from?why? and how to solve this problem

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3J94P/)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#mydiv{
width:200px;
height:100px;
position:relative;
border-radius:0 0 100px 100px ;
background:blue;
left:50px;
top:50px;
animation:rot 4s infinite;

}
@keyframes rot{
  0%{
     transform:rotate(0deg);
  }100%{
     transform:rotate(-360deg);
  }

}
#container{
   overflow:hidden;
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   position:absolute;
   border-radius:70%;
   background:red;
   left:500px;
   top:400px;


}
#container :after{
 content:'';
 display:block;
 width:60px;
 height:60px;
 border-radius:60%;
 background:black;
position:relative;
left:20px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
<div id='mydiv'></div>
<div id='right'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#container :after` selector does not specify which element the `:after` applies to, so it is applied to both `div#mydiv` AND `div#right`.

Just remove the space: `#container:after`

This will only apply the :after element to the #container, rather that it's children & descendents.